# Modify all rows in sql and some data in the middle

Tags: sql

I have problem where I have to change all the existing 13-digit values in a column make it 15 digits. For example:

```
0101001000612
```

This is my already existing data and I want to add two more 0's before 612 and to make it:

```
010100100000612
```

I found the below query somewhere, but it appends data at the end instead of before the last three characters:

```
update loc_state_journal 
set state_journal_id = state_journal_id + '00'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some products have their own string handling functions, instead of ANSI SQL's.) Column data type?

Comment: Do you want first existing 10 characters, then 00, and finally last 3 characters?

Comment: Why don't you store it as `int` and convert it to a (formatted) string wherever you need it to diplay?

Comment: Is all existing data default 13 digits or it may change...?

Comment: @puneetarora What's the datatype of `loc_state_journal` ?

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your question a bit and made some minor grammar adjustments - feel free to roll it back if I've done anything you don't like. A couple of things that might hel you get a better response: exactly what are the rules for adding the two 0s? Are all values in that column 13 digit and need changing, or just some? Is it always before the last 3 characters, or does that depend on the value?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

If you have the column type as `VARCHAR`, then:

```
UPDATE loc_state_journal 
SET state_journal_id =  STUFF(state_journal_id,LEN(state_journal_id )-2,0,'00')
```

If you have column as `BIGINT` then:

```
 UPDATE loc_state_journal 
    SET state_journal_id = cast(stuff(cast(state_journal_id as varchar(15)),LEN(CAST(state_journal_id as VARCHAR(15)))-2,0,'00') as bigint)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and your attempt you have all the data in same form and length. If so, and using SQL Server then you can achieve that using STUFF as following:

```
UPDATE loc_state_journal 
SET state_journal_id = STUFF(state_journal_id,10,0,'00')
```

Comment: Very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

In the calculation below I've included how you would find the first and final part of your query, these calculations are used in the Result;

```
DECLARE @MyVariable varchar(20) = '010100100000612'

SELECT
@MyVariable MyVariable
,SUBSTRING(@MyVariable,1,LEN(@MyVariable)-3) FirstPart
,SUBSTRING(@MyVariable,LEN(@MyVariable)-2,3) FinalPart
,SUBSTRING(@MyVariable,1,LEN(@MyVariable)-3) + '00' + SUBSTRING(@MyVariable,LEN(@MyVariable)-2,3) Result
```

Output

```
MyVariable      FirstPart       FinalPart   Result
010100100000612 010100100000    612         01010010000000612
```

Answer (score 0):

If `state_journal_id`  is text type of data (`CHAR, VARCHAR` etc.), then you need to use `substring` function (If Oracle, else equivalent function) to cut your present data to first 10 characters and last 3 characters and append two `00` in between.

ex:

```
UPDATE loc_state_journal 
SET state_journal_id = SUBSTR(state_journal_id,0,9) ||'00'||SUBSTR(state_journal_id,10,3)
```

if state_journal_id is numeric type (`integer, float` etc), then you can use math functions to achieve desired result.

below example is for Oracle. you can use suitable function for MOD in other databases as well.

```
UPDATE loc_state_journal 
SET state_journal_id = (state_journal_id - MOD(state_journal_id,1000))*100 + MOD(state_journal_id,1000)
```